# Replacing quotes around fields generated by the ConvertTo-Csv cmdlet

Tags: csv, powershell, replace, field

I have a tab delimited csv file that I exported using the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet. When exported it encloses each field in quotes. I am trying to remove just these quotes (I don't want to remove the ones in the fields). I tried this and it didn't work.

```
(Get-Content $root\$filename) | % {$_ -replace('"`t"', "`t")} | Set-Content $root\$filename
```

Values are printed like this "MASSP" separated by tabs. If it was "M"ASSP" I would want to remove the doublequotes on the outside and save the one after the letter "M".

Comment: didn't work how? did it just miss the first quote, pass an error, or not replace any of them?

Comment: The file was produced with the quotes still around the field and field names.

Comment: I think you mean `"M""ASSP"`, not `"M"ASSP"`. `ConvertTo-Csv` escapes _embedded_ double-quotes as `""`.

Comment: I just mean any doublequotes that are produced by convert to csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(Get-Content $root\$filename) |
  % { ($_ -replace '^"|"$|(?<=\t)"|"(?=\t)', '') -replace '""', '"' } |
    Set-Content $root\$filename
```

<sup>- While `` -replace('"`t"', "`t") `` in the question happens to work syntactically, it suggests that you're mistakenly thinking that `-replace` requires *method syntax* for invocation; however, `-replace` is an *operator*.

- Inside the regex argument, since you're using a *single-quoted* string, *regex* escaping rules apply, so a tab must be represented as `\t`.

- Unlike what I originally thought, it *is* possible to read from and write to the same file in a single pipeline, as demonstrated by the OP himself and as pointed out by [Frode F.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/702944/frode-f) in a comment: enclosing `Get-Content $root\$filename` in *parentheses* ensures that the file is read as a whole *up front* and *closed right away*, allowing `Set-Content` to overwrite it.</sup>

The approach uses 2 passes:

- In the first pass, all field-*starting* and field-*ending* double quotes are removed.

  - `^"` matches the 1st field's opening `"`
  - `(?<=\t)"` matches the opening `"` of any field but the 1st.
  - `"(?=\t)` matches the closing quote of any field but the last.
  - `"$` matches the last field's closing `"`.
- In the second pass, all field-*internal* double quotes - which were *doubled* by `ConvertTo-Csv` - are replaced with single instances.

Comment: Thank you mklement0 your solution worked! I've learned a lot here from you guys.

Comment: `(Get-Content file.txt) | % { $_ } | Set-Content file.txt` works. Use a sub-/group-expression around `Get-Content` so it will read the whole file before sending it down the pipeline.

Comment: @FrodeF.: Thanks, I missed that - that's a handy trick (though not suitable for large files); answer updated.

Comment: `Get-content` isn't suitable for big files to be honest. :-)